# NDSolve and Euler method

Tags: differential-equations

I would like to solve $y'(x)=x^2-y^2,y(0)=4$ with two ways, NDSolve and Euler method, and with Runge-Kutta maybe. Then, I 'll try to plot all of them in one graph. I had with NDSolve:

```
s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == x^2-y[x]^2, y[0] == 4}, y, {x, 0, 30}]
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. s], {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
```

For Euler method, I tried:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 - y^2
P[q_, h_, N_] := (u[0] = 1; 
Do[u[n + 1] = 
u[n] + h f[n h + (h q/2), u[n] + (h q/2) f[n h, u[n]]], {n, 0, N}])
P[1, 0.01, 30]
```

but I didn't get anything. I also tried:

```
y = 4; t = 0.0;
n = 20; h = 6/n;
f[y_, t_] := t^2-y^2;
ξ = {y};
Do[(y = y + f[y, t] h;
t = t + h;
ξ = Join[ξ, {y}]), n]

p = Transpose[{Range[0, n]/n, ξ}];

Clear[y, t];
y = 4; t = 0.0;
n = 20; h = 6/n;
f[y_, t_] := t^2- y^2;
ξ = {y};
Do[(y = y + f[t + h/2, y + h f [y, t]/2] h;
t = t + h;
ξ = Join[ξ, {y}]), n]

s = Transpose[{Range[0, n]/n, ξ}];

Clear[y, t];
DSolve[{y'[t] == t^2- y[t]^2, y[0] == 4}, y[t], t]

q = Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. %], {t, 0, 6}, PlotStyle -> Gray];

Show[q, ListPlot[p, PlotStyle -> Blue], ListPlot[s, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

Any help?

Comment: Try `Block[{nn=30, q=0.01}, Graphics[{ Line[Table[{n h + (h q/2), u[n]},{n,  0, nn+1}]]`.  Notes: `Do[]` has no output. `N` is a protected, highly-used, system symbol.  You should not use it for your own purposes.

Answer (score 5):

```
x[0] = 0;(*Supplementary conditions*)
y[0] = 4.;
h = 0.1;
f[x_, y_] := x^2 - y^2
x[n_] := n h + x[0]
y[n_] := y[n] = y[n - 1] + h f[x[n - 1], y[n - 1]]
data = Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, 0, 10}];
Show[Plot[
  Evaluate[yy[x] /. 
    First[NDSolve[{yy'[x] == x^2 - yy[x]^2, yy[0] == 4}, 
      yy[x], {x, 0, 1}]]], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}], 
 ListLinePlot[data, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Mesh -> Full], 
 PlotRange -> {0, 4}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always supply the statement as an argument for NDSolve, Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> "ExplicitEuler"}, or Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> d}} where d is the chosen order you want.