# A system of differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

Consider the following system of differential equations: $$x'(t) = a\, x(t) - b \,x(t) y(t),$$
and $$ y'(t) = c\, x(t) y(t) - d \,y(t),$$
with  $$
x(0) = x_0, y(0) = y_0$$

For example, we may have:

```
a = 2.2; b = 0.03; c = 1.4; d = 0.02;
eq1 = x'[t] == a*x[t] - b*x[t]*y[t]
eq2 = y'[t] == -c*y[t] + d*y[t]*x[t]
sol = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, x[0] == 150, y[0] == 10}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 30}]
gr1 = Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 30}, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, 
Hue[0.7]}, { Dashing[{0.03}], Hue[1]}}, Ticks -> {{{0.01, 0}, {10, "time"}, 
20}, {500, {700, "number"}, 1000}}, LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", 
FontSize -> 16}, PlotLabel -> "solid blue: rabbits, dashed red: foxes"];
gr2 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 30}, PlotStyle -> 
{Thick, Hue[0.3]}, Ticks -> {{{0.01`, 0}, 500, {700, "rabbits"}, 1000}, {500, 
{700, "foxes"}, 1000}}, LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 
16}];
sp = StreamPlot[{2.2` x - 0.03 y x, -1.4 y + 0.02` y x}, {x, 0, 200}, {y, 0, 
150}, StreamScale -> Large]
GraphicsRow[{gr1, gr2, sp}]
f[x_, y_] = {2.2 x - 0.03 x y, -1.4 y + 0.02 x y};
Show[VectorPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}], Frame -> True, 
BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14}]
Show[VectorPlot[
f[x, y]/(10^-8 + Norm[f[x, y]]), {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}], 
Frame -> True, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14}]
```

I can't use a numerical method (e.g. Euler method) instead of `NDSolve`. I need the same method for $m x''(t)=-g x(t)^3$ Is there any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't use a numerical method (e.g. Euler method) instead of `NDSolve`. I need the same method for $mx′′(t)=−gx(t)^3$"? What exactly do you need?

Comment: I don't need to use NDSolve for solving the above system, that's all

Comment: Do you mean you need to solve the problem without `NDSolve`?

Comment: yes, without NDSolve

Comment: Then what have you tried?

Comment: the above code, I don.t know anything else without NDSolve

Comment: But you've already asked a question about Euler method and received an answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/213099/1871). Solving a ODE and a system of ODE with Euler method are just the same. If you have difficulty in understanding that answer, you should continue asking in the comment under that answer, rather than ask essentially the same question again.

Comment: It is possible to paste code so that it needs only minimal editing to be easily read. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful.

Comment: For your second equation, the "energy" $H=p^2/(2m)+gq^4/4$, where $p=mx'(t)$ and $q=x(t)$ is invariant (i.e., a constant function of $t$). So the trajectories trace the curve $H(x(t), m x'(t)) = H(x_0,m x'_0)$ in the $(x,x')$ phase plane.  A similar approach can be done with the first L-V system, using $p = \log x,\ q=\log y$, but it's equivalent to Chris's answer below. I fail to see what it has to do with *Mathematica*, though. It's just math (or physics).

Answer (score 5):

This is the famous [Lotka-Volterra predator-prey model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations).  I don't think there is a closed-form solution for the time dynamics but there is one for the orbits in the phase plane, which is described on that wikipedia page.

You can derive it in Mathematica with

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == (-c*y[x] + d*y[x]*x)/(a*x - b*x*y[x])}, y, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]